# Please identify these two Star Wars ships

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I need help identifying these completed ships. I need names or set numbers to match my minifigures.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

The top one is [8087: TIE Defender](https://brickset.com/sets/8087-1/TIE-Defender)

[image]

The bottom one is [8099: Midi-scale Imperial Star Destroyer](https://brickset.com/sets/8099-1/Midi-scale-Imperial-Star-Destroyer)

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Sets are [TIE Defender (8087)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8087-1&name=TIE%20Defender&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Legends%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

And [Midi-Scale Imperial Star Destroyer (8099)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=91475#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]